# What should the top level of a slime farm be at for maximum efficiency?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building a slime farm and want to get the best rates possible. This most likely means having the top layer able to span large slimes. That being said what should the top level be at to spawn the largest size of slimes?

Comment: Why would it? The technical answer is to dig out a complete slime chunk not higher than Y 39.

Comment: @Alex no, I wanted to know what the top level of a slime farm should be for maximum efficiency, that can be found with data and so is not opinional.